# Creating a dynamic URL in visualforcepage

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce

I hope you can help me, I have limited coding skills, but would like to make a visualforce page in Salesforce with a link button. The linkbutton should be to a relative page, based on the Event.ID, from where the link button is visual.

I have come up with the following:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false"> 
 <apex:pageBlock title="PowerPoint">
 </apex:pageblock>

 <apex:form >

 <apex:commandButton value="Link "
  action="ms-powerpoint:ofe|u|https://"MY LINK"/TestCEM/MeetingPresentations/Opret.pptm?event=1234"/>

 </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Where it says "evnt=1234" I would like to insert my event.id so it is a realtive link: event=event.id

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:page standardController="Event" readonly="true" sidebar="false"> 

    <a href="ms-powerpoint:ofe|u|https://MY LINK/TestCEM/MeetingPresentations/Opret.pptm?event={!Event.Id}">Link</a>
    
    or
    
    <apex:outputLink value="ms-powerpoint:ofe|u|https://MY LINK/TestCEM/MeetingPresentations/Opret.pptm">Link
        <apex:param name="event" value="{!Event.Id}"/>
    </apex:outputLink>

</apex:page>
```

You might not even need Visualforce for this, how about making a new custom field on Event / Activity? Formula field of type text should work very nice.